# Ionic Storage not outputing my stored JSON data correctly - Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-storage

I have something like the following:

```
    Storage.remove({key: 'somedata'}).then(r => {
      Storage.set({key: 'somedata', value: data}).then(g => {
        Storage.get({key : 'somedata'}).then((val) => {
          console.log('Your json is', val);
        });
      });
    });
```

I get data from my API in JSON from and try to store it.

When I then try to output the stored data in the console I get the following

[image: Picture example]

I am wondering how I can get the actual data instead of it being object object

Thanks

Update - screenshot of error with potential solution:

[image]

Comment: you need to parse your json. `JSON.parse(YourData)`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Hello, When I put the val in JSON.parse(val) I get the error of 'TS2345: Argument of type 'GetResult' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: looks like you are setting it wrong. `Storage.set("YourKeyShouldBeString", youData)`. convert your key into string and see. it will be better if you can create a stackblitz with minimum code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, I think you can try this

```
Storage.remove(key).then(r => {
   Storage.set(key, data).then(g => {
      Storage.get(key).then((val) => {
          console.log('Your json is', val);
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Hello, 

When I put the val in JSON.parse(val) I get the error of 'TS2345: Argument of type 'GetResult' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: I think it should be like above code.

Comment: I have a screenshot to the main post showing the error

Comment: Then you can remove JSON.stringify and parse, I think that should work

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to remove

```
Storage.set(key, data).then(g => {
   Storage.get(key).then((val) => {
      console.log('Your json is', val);
   });
});
```